# TCP shutdown with sockets connected through AcceptEx()

Tags: windows, sockets

The documentation for [`AcceptEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx) says:

> When this operation is successfully completed, sAcceptSocket can be
>   passed, but to the following functions only:
>
> - ReadFile
> - WriteFile
> - send
> - WSASend
> - recv
> - WSARecv
> - TransmitFile
> - closesocket
> - setsockopt (only for SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT)

Notice that [`shutdown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481.aspx) is not in the list.  Indeed, invoking `shutdown(sAcceptSocket, SD_SEND)` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` and `WSAGetLastError()` produces error `WSAENOTCONN`:

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.

Why can you not shutdown a socket connected through `AcceptEx()`?  Also, why does the socket not appear as connected since it is already receiving data (the overlapped operation has completed and the completion notification indicates that some `size>0` bytes were received)?

Comment: The client haven't already closed the connection? Do you get the same error if you do `shutdown` directly after `AcceptEx`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: No, the client has not closed the connection.  I'm testing with accepting HTTP requests from Chrome with the "Connection: keep-alive" header.  I get this error whether I send data or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT)` after `AcceptEx()` completes. The accepted socket is not fully associated with the properties of the listening socket, and as such will not be in a fully connected state, until `SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT` is set. Some winsock API functions are affected by that, including `getpeername()`, `getsockname()` and `shutdown()`.

If you use `ConnectEx()` to make an outbound connection, you have to invoke `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT)` after `ConnectEx()` completes before you can then use `shutdown()`.  This is [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532.aspx) on MSDN.  It does not say the same for `AcceptEx()` and `SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT`, but `shutdown()` does have a similar restriction for sockets accepted by `AcceptEx()`.

Comment: I'm already calling `setsockopt()` to make sure that `getpeername()` *et al.* work as expected.  Let me run some tests, I'll get back to you on this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure in which order I original tested, but it works now.  If I remove the call to `setsockopt()`, I get an error again.  Thanks a lot!