# iocp socket close_wait status, how to fix it?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, iocp

It is not easy to write a iocp console server，socket pool and thread pool works well，but after some times leater, the server can not connect again,though nothing wrong happens, why? I use procexp_16.05.1446001339.exe  to check the process properties, I found  lots of close_wait status, after some times again, close_wait status disappears, but the server still can not connect.Why is that? And how to fix it ?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Winsock2.h"
    #include "Windows.h"
    #include "Winbase.h"
    #include "tlhelp32.h"
    #include "tchar.h"
    #include "Psapi.h"
    #include "Winternl.h"
    #include "Shlwapi.h"
    #include "mstcpip.h"
    #include 
    #include "ws2tcpip.h"
    #include "time.h"

    #pragma comment( lib, "Kernel32.lib" )
    #pragma comment( lib, "Shlwapi.lib" )
    #pragma comment( lib, "Psapi.lib" )
    #pragma comment( lib, "Winmm.lib" )
    #pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" )

    #define DATA_BUFSIZE   10240
    #define OP_ACCEPT   1
    #define OP_RECV     2
    #define OP_SEND     3
    #define OP_DIS      4
    #define OP_ONACCEPT 5

    //iocp struct
    struct iocp_overlapped{
        OVERLAPPED  m_ol;                          // 
        int         m_iOpType;                     //do type
        SOCKET      m_skServer;                    //server socket
        SOCKET      m_skClient;                    //client
        DWORD       m_recvBytes;                   //recv msg bytes
        char        m_pBuf[DATA_BUFSIZE];          //recv buf
        WSABUF      m_DataBuf;                     //recv data buf
        int         m_recv_timeout;                //recv timeout
        int         m_send_timeout;
        SOCKADDR_IN m_addrClient;                  //client address
        SOCKADDR_IN m_addrServer;                  //server address
        int         m_isUsed;                      //client is active 1 yes 0 not
        time_t      m_active;                      //the last active time
        int         m_isCrashed;                   //is crashed? 0 not 1 yes
        int         m_online;                      //is online 1 yes 0 not
        int         m_usenum;                      //

        //void (*handler)(int,struct tag_socket_data*);   data->handler(res, data);  
    };




    static SOCKET  m_sock_listen = INVALID_SOCKET;    //the server listen socket

    class WingIOCP{
    private:
        char* m_listen_ip;        //listen ip
        int   m_port;             //listen port
        int   m_max_connect;      //max connection
        int   m_recv_timeout;     //recv timeout
        int   m_send_timeout;     //send timeout

        unsigned long* m_povs;  //clients 

        //iocp worker
        static VOID CALLBACK worker( 
            DWORD dwErrorCode,
            DWORD dwBytesTrans,
            LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped 
            );
        //accept ex
        static BOOL accept(
                SOCKET sAcceptSocket,
                PVOID lpOutputBuffer,
                DWORD dwReceiveDataLength,
                DWORD dwLocalAddressLength,
                DWORD dwRemoteAddressLength,
                LPDWORD lpdwBytesReceived,
                LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
            );
        //disconnect a client socket and reuse it
        static BOOL disconnect( SOCKET client_socket , LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped , DWORD dwFlags = TF_REUSE_SOCKET , DWORD reserved = 0);

        //event callbacks
        static void onconnect( iocp_overlapped *&povl );
        static void ondisconnect( iocp_overlapped *&povl );
        static void onclose( iocp_overlapped *&povl );
        static void onrecv( iocp_overlapped *&povl );
        static void onsend( iocp_overlapped *&povl );
        static void onrun( iocp_overlapped *&povl, DWORD errorcode, int last_error );

        static void onaccept(iocp_overlapped *&pOL);

    public:

        WingIOCP(
            const char* listen       = "0.0.0.0",
            const int   port         = 6998,  
            const int   max_connect  = 10,
            const int   recv_timeout = 3000,
            const int   send_timeout = 3000
            );
        ~WingIOCP();
        BOOL start();
        void wait();
    };

    /**
     * @ construct 
     */
    WingIOCP::WingIOCP( 
        const char* listen,    //listen ip
        const int port,        //listen port
        const int max_connect, //max connect
        const int recv_timeout,//recv timeout in milliseconds 
        const int send_timeout //send timeout in milliseconds
    )
    { 

        this->m_listen_ip      = _strdup(listen);               //listen ip
        this->m_port           = port;                          //listen port
        this->m_max_connect    = max_connect;                   //max connect
        this->m_recv_timeout   = recv_timeout;                  //recv timeout
        this->m_send_timeout   = send_timeout;                  //send timeout                               
        this->m_povs           = new unsigned long[max_connect];//clients 

    }

    /**
     * @ destruct
     */
    WingIOCP::~WingIOCP(){

        if( this->m_listen_ip ) 
        {   
            free(this->m_listen_ip );
            this->m_listen_ip = NULL;
        }

        if( this->m_povs )
        {
            delete[] this->m_povs;
            this->m_povs = NULL;
        }

        if( m_sock_listen != INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            closesocket( m_sock_listen );
            m_sock_listen = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        WSACleanup();
    }

    /**
     *@wait
     */
    void WingIOCP::wait(){
        while( true ){
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    //event callbacks
     void WingIOCP::onconnect( iocp_overlapped *&pOL ){
         printf("%ld onconnect\r\n",pOL->m_skClient);
         pOL->m_online = 1;
         pOL->m_active = time(NULL);

         if( setsockopt( pOL->m_skClient, SOL_SOCKET,SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT,(const char *)&pOL->m_skServer,sizeof(pOL->m_skServer) ) != 0 )
         {
             //setsockopt fail
             //printf("1=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
             WSASetLastError(0);
             return;
         }

         // set send timeout
         if( pOL->m_send_timeout > 0 )
         {
             if( setsockopt( pOL->m_skClient, SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char*)&pOL->m_send_timeout,sizeof(pOL->m_send_timeout)) !=0 )
             {
                 //setsockopt fail
                // printf("2=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
             }
         }
         if( pOL->m_recv_timeout > 0 )
         {
             if( setsockopt( pOL->m_skClient, SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&pOL->m_recv_timeout,sizeof(pOL->m_recv_timeout)) != 0 )
             {
                 //setsockopt fail
                // printf("3=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
             }
         }

         linger so_linger;
         so_linger.l_onoff  = TRUE;
         so_linger.l_linger = 0; // without close wait status
         if( setsockopt( pOL->m_skClient,SOL_SOCKET,SO_LINGER,(const char*)&so_linger,sizeof(so_linger) ) != 0 ){
            // printf("31=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
         } 

         //get client ip and port
         int client_size = sizeof(pOL->m_addrClient);  
         ZeroMemory( &pOL->m_addrClient , sizeof(pOL->m_addrClient) );

         if( getpeername( pOL->m_skClient , (SOCKADDR *)&pOL->m_addrClient , &client_size ) != 0 ) 
         {
             //getpeername fail
            // printf("4=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
         }

        // printf("%s %d connect\r\n",inet_ntoa(pOL->m_addrClient.sin_addr), pOL->m_addrClient.sin_port);

         //keepalive open
         int dt     = 1;
         DWORD dw   = 0;
         tcp_keepalive live ;     
         live.keepaliveinterval = 5000;     //连接之后 多长时间发现无活动 开始发送心跳吧 单位为毫秒 
         live.keepalivetime     = 1000;     //多长时间发送一次心跳包 1分钟是 60000 以此类推     
         live.onoff             = TRUE;     //是否开启 keepalive

         if( setsockopt( pOL->m_skClient, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&dt, sizeof(dt) ) != 0 )
         {
             //setsockopt fail
            // printf("5=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
         }           

         if( WSAIoctl(   pOL->m_skClient, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &live, sizeof(live), NULL, 0, &dw, &pOL->m_ol , NULL ) != 0 )
         {
             //WSAIoctl error
            // printf("6=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
         }

         memset(pOL->m_pBuf,0,DATA_BUFSIZE);
         //post recv
         pOL->m_DataBuf.buf = pOL->m_pBuf;  
         pOL->m_DataBuf.len = DATA_BUFSIZE;  
         pOL->m_iOpType     = OP_RECV;

         DWORD RecvBytes        = 0;
         DWORD Flags            = 0;

         int code           = WSARecv(pOL->m_skClient,&(pOL->m_DataBuf),1,&RecvBytes,&Flags,&(pOL->m_ol),NULL);
         int error_code     = WSAGetLastError();

         if( 0 != code )
         {
             if( WSA_IO_PENDING != error_code ) 
             {
                // printf("7=>onconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
                 return;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             //recv complete
             onrecv( pOL );
         }
     }
     void WingIOCP::ondisconnect( iocp_overlapped *&pOL ){
        // printf("ondisconnect error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
         WSASetLastError(0);
         pOL->m_online   = 0;                                //set offline
         pOL->m_active   = time(NULL);                       //the last active time
         pOL->m_iOpType  = OP_ONACCEPT;                      //reset status
         pOL->m_isUsed   = 0;                                //
         ZeroMemory(pOL->m_pBuf,sizeof(char)*DATA_BUFSIZE);  //clear buf



         if( !BindIoCompletionCallback( (HANDLE)pOL->m_skClient ,worker,0) ){
            // printf("BindIoCompletionCallback error %ld\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
         }
         //post acceptex
         int error_code     = accept( pOL->m_skClient,pOL->m_pBuf,0,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)+16,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)+16,NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)pOL );
         //printf("accept error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
         int last_error     = WSAGetLastError() ;

         if( !error_code && ERROR_IO_PENDING != last_error ){

         }
         //printf("2=>ondisconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n================================================\r\n\r\n", WSAGetLastError());

          //printf("21=>ondisconnect some error happened , error code %d \r\n================================================\r\n\r\n", WSAGetLastError());

         WSASetLastError(0);
     }

     void WingIOCP::onaccept(iocp_overlapped *&pOL){
         pOL->m_active   = time(NULL);                       //the last active time
         pOL->m_iOpType  = OP_ACCEPT;                        //reset status
         printf("%ld reuse socket real complete , error code %d \r\n", pOL->m_skClient,WSAGetLastError());

         WSASetLastError(0);
     }
     void WingIOCP::onclose( iocp_overlapped *&pOL ){
        // printf("%ld close\r\n", pOL->m_skClient);

         SOCKET m_sockListen = pOL->m_skServer;
         SOCKET m_client     = pOL->m_skClient;
         int send_timeout    = pOL->m_send_timeout;
         int recv_timeout    = pOL->m_recv_timeout;
         pOL->m_iOpType = OP_DIS;

         shutdown( pOL->m_skClient, SD_BOTH );
         //socket reuse
         if( !disconnect( pOL->m_skClient , &pOL->m_ol ) && WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()) {
            // printf("1=>onclose some error happened , error code %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
         }
         //printf("onclose complete %d \r\n", WSAGetLastError());
     }
     void WingIOCP::onrecv( iocp_overlapped *&pOL ){
         pOL->m_active = time(NULL);
        // printf("recv:\r\n%s\r\n\r\n",pOL->m_pBuf);
         ZeroMemory(pOL->m_pBuf,DATA_BUFSIZE);      
     }
     void WingIOCP::onsend( iocp_overlapped *&povl ){

     }
     void WingIOCP::onrun( iocp_overlapped *&povl, DWORD errorcode, int last_error ){}
    /**
     * @ acceptex
     */
    BOOL WingIOCP::accept(
        SOCKET  sAcceptSocket,
        PVOID   lpOutputBuffer,
        DWORD   dwReceiveDataLength,
        DWORD   dwLocalAddressLength,
        DWORD   dwRemoteAddressLength,
        LPDWORD lpdwBytesReceived,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    )
    {
        WSASetLastError(0);
        if( m_sock_listen == INVALID_SOCKET || !lpOverlapped ) 
        {   
            return 0;
        }
        GUID guidAcceptEx   = WSAID_ACCEPTEX;
        DWORD dwBytes       = 0;
        LPFN_ACCEPTEX lpfnAcceptEx;

        int res= WSAIoctl( m_sock_listen, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &guidAcceptEx, 
            sizeof(guidAcceptEx), &lpfnAcceptEx, sizeof(lpfnAcceptEx), &dwBytes, NULL, NULL );

        if( 0 != res )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return lpfnAcceptEx( m_sock_listen, sAcceptSocket, lpOutputBuffer, dwReceiveDataLength,
            dwLocalAddressLength, dwRemoteAddressLength, lpdwBytesReceived, lpOverlapped );        
    }

    /**
     * @ disconnect socket and reuse the socket
     */
    BOOL WingIOCP::disconnect( SOCKET client_socket , LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped , DWORD dwFlags  , DWORD reserved  )
    {
        WSASetLastError(0);
        if( client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET || !lpOverlapped ) 
        {   
            return 0;
        }
        GUID GuidDisconnectEx = WSAID_DISCONNECTEX;
        DWORD dwBytes = 0;
        LPFN_DISCONNECTEX lpfnDisconnectEx; 

        if( 0 != WSAIoctl( client_socket,SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,&GuidDisconnectEx,
            sizeof(GuidDisconnectEx),&lpfnDisconnectEx,sizeof(lpfnDisconnectEx),&dwBytes,NULL,NULL))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return lpfnDisconnectEx(client_socket,lpOverlapped,/*TF_REUSE_SOCKET*/dwFlags,reserved);
    }



    /**
     * @ iocp worker thread
     */
    VOID CALLBACK WingIOCP::worker( DWORD dwErrorCode,DWORD dwBytesTrans,LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped )
    {
        //why here get the error code 87 ?
        //printf("worker error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
        if( NULL == lpOverlapped  )
        {
            //not real complete
            SleepEx(20,TRUE);//set warn status
            WSASetLastError(0);
            return;
        }

        //get overlapped data
        iocp_overlapped*  pOL = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpOverlapped, iocp_overlapped, m_ol);

        //just a test
        onrun( pOL, dwErrorCode, WSAGetLastError() );

        switch( pOL->m_iOpType )
        {
        case OP_DIS:
            ondisconnect(pOL);
            break;
        case OP_ONACCEPT:
            onaccept(pOL);
            break;
            case OP_ACCEPT: 
            {
                //new client connect
                onconnect( pOL );
            }
            break;
            case OP_RECV:
            {
                pOL->m_recvBytes = dwBytesTrans;
                //check client offline
                if( 0 == dwBytesTrans || WSAECONNRESET ==  WSAGetLastError() || ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED ==  WSAGetLastError()){
                    onclose( pOL );
                } 
                else
                {   //recv msg from client
                    pOL->m_recvBytes = dwBytesTrans;
                    onrecv( pOL );
                }   
            }
            break;
            case OP_SEND:
            {

            }
            break;


        }

        WSASetLastError(0);

    }
    BOOL WingIOCP::start(){ 

        do{ 

            WSADATA wsaData; 
            if( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0 )
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            if(LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
            {
                break;
            }  

            m_sock_listen = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED); 
            if( INVALID_SOCKET == m_sock_listen )
            {
                break;
            }

            //bind the worker thread
            BOOL bReuse      = TRUE;
            BOOL bind_status = ::BindIoCompletionCallback((HANDLE)( m_sock_listen ), worker, 0 );
            if( !bind_status )
            {
                break;
            }

            //set option SO_REUSEADDR 
            if( 0 != ::setsockopt( m_sock_listen, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,(LPCSTR)&bReuse, sizeof(BOOL) ) )
            {
                //some error happened
                break;
            }


            struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress; 
            ZeroMemory(&ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress)); 

            ServerAddress.sin_family        = AF_INET;                    
            ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr   = inet_addr( this->m_listen_ip );          
            ServerAddress.sin_port          = htons( this->m_port );   

            if ( SOCKET_ERROR == bind( m_sock_listen, (struct sockaddr *) &ServerAddress, sizeof( ServerAddress ) ) )
            {
                break;
            }  

            if( 0 != listen( m_sock_listen , SOMAXCONN ) )
            {
                break;
            }
            //printf("1=>start get error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
            WSASetLastError(0);
            //socket pool
            for( int i = 0 ; i m_max_connect ; i++ ) 
            {

                SOCKET client = WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,0,0,WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
                if( INVALID_SOCKET == client ) 
                {   
                    continue;
                }

                if( !BindIoCompletionCallback( (HANDLE)client ,worker,0) )
                {
                    closesocket(client);
                    continue;
                }

                iocp_overlapped *povl = new iocp_overlapped();
                if( NULL == povl )
                {
                    closesocket(client);
                    continue;
                }

                DWORD dwBytes = 0;
                ZeroMemory(povl,sizeof(iocp_overlapped));

                povl->m_iOpType         = OP_ACCEPT;
                povl->m_skServer            = m_sock_listen;
                povl->m_skClient            = client;
                povl->m_recv_timeout        = m_recv_timeout;
                povl->m_isUsed          = 0;
                povl->m_active          = 0; 
                povl->m_isCrashed       = 0;
                povl->m_online          = 0;
                povl->m_usenum          = 1;

                int server_size = sizeof(povl->m_addrServer);  
                ZeroMemory(&povl->m_addrServer,server_size);
                getpeername(povl->m_skServer,(SOCKADDR *)&povl->m_addrServer,&server_size);  

                int error_code = accept( povl->m_skClient, povl->m_pBuf, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)+16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)+16, NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)povl );
                int last_error = WSAGetLastError() ;
                if( !error_code && ERROR_IO_PENDING != last_error ) 
                {

                    closesocket( client );
                    client = povl->m_skClient = INVALID_SOCKET;
                    delete povl;
                    povl = NULL; 
                    //printf("client=>crate error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
                }else{
                    this->m_povs[i] = (unsigned long)povl;
                }
                //here all the last error is 997 , means nothing error happened
                //printf("client=>start get error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
                WSASetLastError(0);
            }
            //printf("last start get error %d\r\n",WSAGetLastError());
            WSASetLastError(0);
            return TRUE;

        } while( 0 );

        if( m_sock_listen != INVALID_SOCKET )
        {
            closesocket( m_sock_listen );
            m_sock_listen = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        WSACleanup();

        return FALSE;
    }




    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        WingIOCP *iocp  = new WingIOCP();
        iocp->start();
        iocp->wait();
        delete iocp;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Servers don't connect. Clients connect.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to *any* CLOSE_WAIT issue is to *close the socket*. Evidently you are leaking sockets at end of stream or on an error.

Answer (score -1):

Correct [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) usage like MS sample.

[EDIT] After some search I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174331/47733) issue about AcceptEx.

Good lock.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how to do with "Correct setsockopt usage"?

Comment: i test many times, it seems like that the socket reuse fail, and consume all the sockets from the pool, why? i use the disconnex and set TF_REUSE_SOCKET success

Comment: None of this has anything to do with CLOSE_WAIT.